# Which is better: Parsing big data each time from the DB or caching the result?

Tags: sql, database, performance

I have a problem regarding the system performance. In the DB table there will be a big XML data in every record. My concern is that if I should parse the XML data each time from the DB to get the attributes and information in the XML. The other choice could be parsing the XML once and catching them. The XML size averages 100KB and there will be 10^10 records. How to solve this space vs computing performance problem? My guess is to catch the result(important attributes in the XML). Because parsing 10^10 records per query is not a easy task. Plus the parsed attributes can be used as the index.

Comment: Can you parse it on update and save it as normal data somewhere so it's more convenient to query?

Comment: Which database? If using SQL Server, then use a column of type `xml`. That will parse the data when it's first entered, after which it will be in a "binary XML" format - both fast and compact.

Comment: Yeah. I think it's a good way. There are maybe 100 attributes in the XML and important ones are like 20. I want to add these 20 attributes in the table column. When the XML column in the record changes, parse the XML and update the 20 columns. How about this design?

Comment: I think I will be using Informix database.

Comment: Why not measure it on your system with your data, rather than asking us to *guess* at the performance of each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to parse it all *every query* you undoubtly should cache the results, perhaps put the full generated product into a single database field or a file for future use, or at last until something is changed, just like a forum system do.

Repeating an expensive process on a massive amount of data knowing you will always get the same result is a real waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use some of the attributes from the XML for indexing, better to add them as columns to the table.

Regarding parsing XML, 100kb is hardly a size that would affect performance. Moreover, you can read and store the XML (as is) in a string while fetching the records and parse it only when you want to show / use those additional attributes.

Comment: Note that SQL Server also supports XML indexes on `xml` columns. You can keep the data as `xml`, at the same time indexing by an attribute.

Comment: My current design is going to store the XML in a string and catch the important attributes in the table fields when the XML data updates. If Infomix doesn't support such property as SQL Server does, I will indexing these important attributes parsed from the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the best choice: parse the XML and store its data in tables were they belong. If you really really need the original XML verbatim, keep it as a blob and otherwise ignore it.

(I think you meant *cache*, by the way, not catch.)

Comment: Yes, this could be the best practice.But it has some difficulties mainly because the XML is quite complicated and I rarely care about anything other than those important attributes. Just in case I still prefer storing it.